# How many millilitres of liquids on Ryanair flight?

Tags: usa, air-travel

How much milliliters can uoy have on Ryanair (airline)? I’m going in 2 weeks

I tried looking at the internet but it didn’t say anything about it.

Comment: are you traveling from where to from?

Comment: Ryanair doesn't serve the USA.  Why have you used this tag?  Voting to place on hold as "unclear" until this can be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're departing from a US airport (which I assume given your tag choice), you can take liquids in travel-sized containers [to a maximum of 3.4 US fluid ounces or 100 mL each](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/frequently-asked-questions/what-3-1-1-liquids-rule).  These must fit within a 1 U.S. quart (946 mL) bag.

Assuming RyanAir but not from the US, this is likely subject to EU rules but is typically 100 mL per liquid, with a 1-litre bag; [see this link here](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/aviation-security-policy/lags_en).

This assumes you are bringing the liquids from outside the secure area.  You can bring any reasonable amount of liquids with you that were purchased or acquired behind the security check.

Comment: Ryanair doesn't cross the Atlantic.

Comment: @choster Didn't think so, but the poster put a USA tag on his question so I thought I'd cover all the bases.

Comment: While Ryanair don't fly to the USA, they do have an agreement with Air Europa such that Air Europa flights can be bought on Ryanair's website, which could cause some confusion.

Comment: @skifans But then Ryanair is not the operating carrier, and it is Air Europa's rules, not Ryanair's, which prevail. In any case, I had been about to answer that airport security, not airline policy, is what generally limits liquid amounts, and that it would be no different from one airline to the other, but then I considered that Ryanairesque airlines might not care about your hand lotion, but might arbitrarily ban drinks in the hopes of selling you some in-flight.